# Run-time error 424 on Excel VBA "Object required" for very basic worksheet copy function

Tags: excel, vba, copy, worksheet

Here is a snippet of the macro that I am having a problem with, the error message appears just as it does in the larger macro it is a part of :

```
Sub copyWorksheet()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Manifest Blank").Copy(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

End Sub
```

This seems to work as intended, it creates a duplicate of my worksheet called "Manifest Blank" but then shows an error message : Run-time error 424 on Excel VBA "Object required"

I have tried :

- renaming evertyhing "sheets" instead of "worksheets"
- changing "worksheets.count" to an actual number or a named worksheet
- changing the named worksheet to an actual number or a named worksheet

All of these result in the intended behaviour but all still show the run-time error 424.

Comment: There is no return on `.copy`

Comment: @Warcupine - well technically `.Copy` returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: @BigBen That would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` is a method of `worksheet`. It doesn't return the worksheet it self.

But the new sheet will always be the `ActiveSheet`

```vb
Sub copyWorksheet()

Worksheets("Manifest Blank").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: For confidence, after copy, Set  ws1=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Comment: I knew it would be something like this, but I am still early in my learning.Thank you!